# Suitable High Voltage source for CRT experiment

Tags: high-voltage

I bought a Soviet-era 'new/old stock' Cathode Ray Tube (CRT), historically intended for use in a small oscilloscope. My goal is to explore atomic diffraction (with a hack):

[image: CRT]

But as a chemist/physicist I'm not well versed in one of the critical components of those planned experiments: the High Voltage Supply (HVS, up to approx. 7,000 V).

This being a 'backyard science' project budget is of course important.

Window shopping for something suitable showed up a rather bewildering array of different possibilities with a wide price range and for the second hand options often very poorly written technical specifications.

So far I'm gravitating somewhat [towards this ebay listing](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/265477501365?hash=item3dcfb131b5:g:5UgAAOSwhWRauTWg). To avoid linkrot I'll summarise its advertised characteristics, below.

[image: HVS]

> *Very high voltage regulated power supply module*.
>
> This module allows, from a power source of 8 and 12V, to obtain an
> output voltage of 300 to 10,000V adjustable by a potentiometer.
>
> The available power is around ten watts, ie 1mA at 10,000V or 10mA at
> 1000V.
>
> An output is provided for the connection of a voltmeter for displaying
> the output voltage with 1V = 1000V.
>
> The card is delivered wired and tested, accompanied by its user
> manual, connection plan, diagram and description, ready for use.

But I'm not at all certain of its suitability. From the description and bearing in mind my awful ignorance on HVSs I'm not even sure the advertised  voltage is AC or DC!

Please help.

Comment: I wouldn't entertain any module that didn't have evidence of quality manufacture and a pdf data sheet.

Comment: For the HVS featured it actually says *Documentation on request*  but I'm not sure whether that would be pre or post-sale. What specifically would you want to know?

Comment: THT power supplies are generally sophisticated devices, safety first!

Comment: @Gert There's nothing specific - I want to see evidence of good quality and a data sheet before I would consider putting it on a short list. Also note that the stupid peebay page says it can produce "300 A" and that for sure means I wouldn't even consider it for investigation period. Think how important your experiment is and how much you value your time and how much the experiment results may be mocked/dismissed if you use cruddy parts. I need ALL the boxes to be ticked when I buy something like this.

Comment: Poor description, including use of jargon that excludes *novices and 'pure' scientists* are a problem I reported in the question. But to be fair, I didn't even see the "300 A"

Comment: "300 A 10 000 volt" must be read "300 to 10 000 volt" ... French "distortion".

Comment: Actually, I remember now reading it that way. Maybe it was relisted?

Comment: There are many on-web DIY EHT supplies available. Many use TV line output transformers which gives you a device that is rated for the voltages involved if used properly. This is not a recommendation :-) but [THIS](https://rimstar.org/science_electronics_projects/high_voltage_power_supply_w_flyback_transformer_builtin_diodes.htm) webpage seems like an OK idea starter.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks Russell!

Answer (score 0):

From [wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Multiplicateur_de_tension#/Diff%C3%A9rentes_configurations_de_circuits)
Reverse use of two transformers epoxy molded 15 VA, 220V - 2 * 6V or 2 * 12V.
Diodes are individual fast 1N4007G (1000V/1A). capacitors 1000 V isolated.
The low voltage input 2 * 6V or 2 * 12V are connected to a sine wave whose frequency is chosen for a "maximum" output. A resistor must be connected at output as "discharger" capacitors.

**SAFETY RULES AS USUAL FOR VERY HIGH VOLTAGES !!!**

[image]

Comment: I'm not looking for something home-cooked: *But as a chemist/physicist I'm not well versed in one of the critical components of those planned experiments: the High Voltage Supply (HVS, up to approx. 7,000 V)*

Comment: Ok ... . Anyway, be careful, for anybody ... and without any exception.

Comment: Don't you think that advising a HV novice of a homemade device, then telling them to be careful is a little oxymoronic? Anyway, that's for your effort.

Comment: No. Using a homemade or professional device is also "harmful" for anybody. ... What is "oxymoronic" ?

Comment: Are you really going to argue that a HV homemade device, put together by an electronics novice would be as safe as a decent off-the-shelf device (possibly used but tested)? An oxymoron is an internal contradiction (a "young old man" e.g.)

Comment: Ok for the unknown word. I say only that the "safety" rules must be known for the "use" of such a device, novice or not. And if you know these "rules", then you can also make it and use it, with some "guidance".